# IPN (notify URL) page is not being called

Tags: javascript, asp.net, paypal

I am working on PayPal sandbox. Transaction is working perfectly and return URL is being called perfectly, but the IPN (notify URL) page is not being called.

I have enabled notify URL from account also. Both caller and listener pages are uploaded on server. Uploaded listener page's URL is set in my code like following. But notify URL is not being called.

```
<script 
data-env="sandbox" 
data-callback="http://example.com/IpnPage.aspx" 
data-tax="2" 
data-shipping="5" 
data-currency="USD" 
data-amount="<%= Session["final_total"]%>"
data-quantity="1" 
data-name="Fees"
data-number="123"
data-custom="<%= Session["sb"]%>"
data-return="http://example.com/IpnPage.aspx"
  ....></script>
```

Comment: Have you tried testing the IPN calls from the IPN Simulator?
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/ipn_simulator

Answer (score 0):

Check the IPN History of the account that should be sending the IPN's.  Here you can confirm or deny that PayPal is indeed sending the IPN's.  You can also see the result to see whether it shows completed or failed.  It could be that your script has an issue with it.

Also check your own web server logs to see if that URL is getting hit and returning a failure of some sort.

If IPN History doesn't show any notifications being sent then you don't have it configured correctly.   I'd need to get a look at your actual API request as the code you put here seems to be what generates it, but that doesn't help.  Need to see the actual request.